# Scala A companion Object Vs. Scala Class new Object

Tags: scala, object, companion-object

Here is the code and the output:

```
//A scala class with a private variable and one method
class A {
  private var a1 = "Zoom"
  def A1(): Unit = {
    println("A1 Class")
  }
}

//A companion object
object A {

  def A2(): Unit = {
    println("A1 Obj")
    val objA = new A
    objA.A1()
    println("a1 -> "+ objA.a1)
  }
}

Output
======
A1 Obj
A1 Class
a1 -> Zoom
```

Now my doubt is if I don't wanna use new operator to create an Object of A class how can **A** companion object will print a1(private variable) value and also access the A1 method of A class. I mean to say I wanna access both the members of Companion Class A through the companion object A.

```
//A companion object
object A {

  def A2(): Unit = {
    println("A1 Obj")

    A.A1()  //It should print A1 Class

    println("a1 -> "+ A.a1) //It should print Zoom
  }
}
```

The above code snippet should also work fine because in Mardin Odersky's book it has been written that *A class and its companion object can access each other’s private members.*

Comment: First using `var` and mutability is not the most idiomatic way to doing with Scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because in Mardin Odersky's book it has been written that A class and its companion object can access each other’s private members

This just means that you are allowed to access `objA.a1` in the first snippet from `object A`, even though it isn't inside `class A` (and similarly, if you have any private members in `object A`, you can access them from `class A`). It isn't relevant to the second snippet at all.

> Now my doubt is if I don't wanna use new operator to create an Object of A class how can A companion object will print a1(private variable) value and also access the A1 method of A class.

Well, you need to use `new` *somewhere*, because only instances of `class A` have `A1()` method and `a1` field.

Note that the main special relationship between `class A` and `object A` is this special visibility rule (and other details are probably irrelevant to you at this stage of learning). So for `A1()` calls it doesn't at all matter that you have a companion object; it could equally be `object B`.

You can make `object A` an instance of `class A` by writing `object A extends A`, but this would just hide the `new` call in code generated by compiler.

Comment: Thank you. @Alexey Can you please let me know - what are the other details and where I can learn more.

Comment: @PardeepSharma You'll learn about them when you get to implicits.